# How to check some command from client in my servlet?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

Greetings to all people.
I have some problem in some deсision in my web project.

I am using jsp and servlets (js, and some other view features..).
For example, i want to change user information and some controller in my web app must to see this command.

In Spring MVC i always used mapping, something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/changePassword/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Or like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/savePersonData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

In Spring, methods, with special mapping, saw my command in the form from client(jsp, or else):

```
<form:form id="personData" name="personData" action="savePersonData" method='POST'>
```

But i don't know how to made the same thing using servlets to make the correct and optimal decision for code.
Thank you for your attention and i hope you can help me with this problem.

Best regards, davakin111.

Comment: Strong recommendation: get a copy of [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html), if you're not already using it.  Not exactly what you're asking about ... but absolutely indispensable.

Comment: Thank's i will read about it. I must to say, it's an interesting thing. I heard about it, but i had never used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The preferable option is to use servlet filters.

**You can identify the users' actions using an http filter. The below code which use spring MVC helps you. 
This filter identifies the requests immediately after receiving the request to server and before reaching the controller method.**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class UserRequestsIdentificationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

       if(request.getRequestURI().contains("/changePassword/") ||  request.getRequestURI().contains("/savePersonData") ) {
                //Do your required actions here

       }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. This is it :) 
Best answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure why down voted ? It would be good to comment and tell the reason.

Comment: I am trying to set +1 to your answer, because its really helped me, but something happens and i am getting thoose message: Thanks for feedback...and so else...

Or you meant the down vote of my question?

Answer (score 2):

Create form in jsp or html

```
  <form action="servlet/Register" method="post">  
   </form>
```

Then servlet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet>  
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/servlet/Register</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then defines the servlet

```
public class Register extends HttpServlet {  
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  
  }
}
```

Complete example is at http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-registration-form-in-servlet